# How to get details of on which localhost karate UI test are running

Tags: karate

I am running a UI test in karate where I need to fetch the details of local host where test are running in karate, earlier I was using selenium to the same task with the following code

```
  ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
  WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
  ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
  HttpCommandExecutor executor = (HttpCommandExecutor) driver.getCommandExecutor();
  URL url = executor.getAddressOfRemoteServer();
```

And this url was returning

> http://localhost:7150

Is there way to get these details in karate framework for UI tests.

Comment: @Perter Thomas: Sorry on missing on some question where I have not accepted the answer, but I have done it now. However by any chance do you have answer to the above question

Answer (score 1):

I am able to fetch the port number from karate web driver

```
 * def opt = driver.getOptions()
 * def port =  opt.port
```

And then appending to string "http://localhost:"+port which solves the problem.